# Are Mathf.Ceil and Mathf.CeilToInt equal?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The question is in the title, as from the Unity scripting reference, both

> "Return the smallest integer greater to or equal to f."

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you try it out yourself?

Comment: OK I know the output seems the same, my question is about the mechanism in behind.

Comment: I looked their documentations and looks like `Mathf.Ceil` returns `float` and `Mathf.CeilToInt` returns `int`.

Comment: Also from [this link for `Mathf.Ceil`](http://ws.cis.sojo-u.ac.jp/~izumi/Unity_Documentation_jp/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Ceil.html); Rounds `f` to the next (larger) integer value.

Comment: Well that's right, though i had read the doc, probably with some dirt in my eyes. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @NightCoder: if documentation is wrong, please fill a bug report to Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathf.Ceil returns a float and Mathf.CeilToInt returns an int. If given the same input, both will return the same number that will certainly pass a ==; however, they are not the same in terms of representation.